# Missed connection in Spring Beans Dependancies diagram with intellijIDEA

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, diagram, spring-bean

I'm working on a simple Spring Application with 3 classes :

- ProductService
- ProductRepo
- ProductConfig

I try to show the diagram of Beans Dependencies

for a particular Bean  **ProductService  **

here is the code of the three classes

**ProductService**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductService { 
    private final ProductRepo productRepo;
}
```

**ProductRepo**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Repository
public class ProductRepo {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
}
```

**ProductConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com")
public class ProductConfig{

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        return new DriverManagerDataSource(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productnew",
                "root",
                "root");
    }
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
}
```

however that the **productService** injects a dependency of the **ProductRepo**,I did not find this communication ( for **productService** bean I just find the association between productService and productConfig ) as it is shown in the image.

[Spring Beans Dependencies Diagram ---ZOOM on productService Bean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X6Dj.jpg)

I try to refresh IntellijIDEA and remove caches and indexes for all projects but the problem still exists

Comment: Could you upload a project sample at https://uploads.jetbrains.com ? (do not forget to specify the UploadID here)

Comment: 2023_03_15_2Bw9brrnYnFeoGwGbEsH42

Comment: Please check how it works in the 2022.3.3 build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download Did I understand correctly that to reproduce it you selected ProductService bean in the Spring tool window?

Comment: Thanks for your interaction, no I  just select & click right ProductService ->Spring Diagrams -> Beans Dependencies.

Comment: I made the 2022.3.3 update of intellijIDEA but the problem is still present..

Comment: I reported issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317510/Missing-connection-in-Spring-Beans-Dependencies-diagram. Please follow it for updates.